# How can I programmatically change a listbox margin?

Tags: c#, listbox, margin

I am trying to change the margin around a set of programmatically generated listboxes using the following code:

```
newListBox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

However this gives me the error:

```
the type or namespace Thickness could not be found
```

I tried adding `using System.Windows` namespace but I still get the same error. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`System.Windows.Thickness`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx) is part of the Presentation Framework. If you arent using WPF or Silverlight try referencing *PresentationFramework.dll* to get access to the `Thickness` structure.

But I'm afraid that in this case your `ListBox.Margin` won't accept an object of type `Thickness`. Try [**`System.Windows.Forms.Padding`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.padding.aspx) if you're using WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for `Padding`.  See [Control.Margin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.margin.aspx)

```
newListBox.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Intellisence is your friend.  As you can see, you want to use a Padding object.

[image]